# Duplicate the objects in python

Tags: python, yolov8

I need to do Augmentation to dataset, and I am planning to do the way where I can duplicate the object that annotated already to multiple times in the same image.

Is there any source that may help? please if any clarification needed let me know.

Comment: what have you tried so far? pls give us some code

Comment: @MrIrrelevant i did not tried anything yet , i just need explination and sources